# Android ScrollView troubles inside relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout

In my android app I need a layout as shown below

[image]

A relative layout is used as the parent layout inside  I use 4 relative layout to arrange the contents- header layout 1,header layout 2, content layout(objRLScrollView -scroll view is inside this layout) and a footer layout

I use the below code to create the above layout

```
    public class Login1 extends Activity {




     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
           this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

            RelativeLayout objRLBody=new RelativeLayout(this);
            objRLBody.setId(1001);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams objLLBodyParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
            objRLBody.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d8e4f3"));
            objRLBody.setLayoutParams(objLLBodyParams); 


            /* header portion starts here*/

            RelativeLayout objRLActionBar=new RelativeLayout(this);
            objRLActionBar.setId(1002);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams objRLActionBarParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,50);
            objRLActionBarParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP); 
            objRLActionBar.setLayoutParams(objRLActionBarParams);
            objRLActionBar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2e4862"));



            objRLBody.addView(objRLActionBar);


            RelativeLayout objRLSelectedActionBar=new RelativeLayout(this);
            objRLSelectedActionBar.setId(1003);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams objRLSelectedActionBarParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            objRLSelectedActionBarParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,objRLActionBar.getId()); 
            objRLSelectedActionBar.setLayoutParams(objRLSelectedActionBarParams);
            objRLSelectedActionBar.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            objRLSelectedActionBar.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.LEFT);


            TextView objTVSelectedAction = new TextView(this); 
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams objTVSelectedActionParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            objTVSelectedAction.setLayoutParams(objTVSelectedActionParams);
            objTVSelectedAction.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            objTVSelectedAction.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            objTVSelectedAction.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,18);
            objTVSelectedAction.setText("Scroll Test"); 
            objTVSelectedAction.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            objTVSelectedAction.setPadding(4, 0, 4, 0);
            objTVSelectedAction.setId(1004);
            objRLSelectedActionBar.addView(objTVSelectedAction);  


            objRLBody.addView(objRLSelectedActionBar);

            /* header portion ends here*/



            /* Relative layout which hold scroll view*/
            RelativeLayout objRLScrollView = new RelativeLayout(this); 
            objRLScrollView.setId(1005);
            objRLScrollView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d8e4f3"));
            objRLScrollView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams objRLScrollViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
            objRLScrollViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW ,objTVSelectedAction.getId());


            ScrollView  objScrollView=new ScrollView(this);
            objScrollView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            objScrollView.setFillViewport(true);



            /* contents */

            RelativeLayout objRLContent = new RelativeLayout(this); 
            objRLContent.setId(1006);
            objRLContent.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d8e4f3"));
            objRLContent.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams objRLContentParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
           // objRLContentParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW ,objTVSelectedAction.getId()); 
            objRLContent.setLayoutParams(objRLContentParams);                


                  /* adding layouts containing Edittext (for testing scroll view) */

                RelativeLayout rl2= addEditText(objRLContent,null,1);
                RelativeLayout rl3= addEditText(objRLContent,rl2,2);
                RelativeLayout rl4= addEditText(objRLContent,rl3,3);
                RelativeLayout rl5= addEditText(objRLContent,rl4,4);
                RelativeLayout rl6= addEditText(objRLContent,rl5,5);
                RelativeLayout rl7= addEditText(objRLContent,rl6,6);
                RelativeLayout rl8= addEditText(objRLContent,rl7,7);
                RelativeLayout rl9= addEditText(objRLContent,rl8,8);
                RelativeLayout rl10= addEditText(objRLContent,rl9,9);
                RelativeLayout rl11= addEditText(objRLContent,rl10,10);
                RelativeLayout rl12= addEditText(objRLContent,rl11,11);
                RelativeLayout rl13= addEditText(objRLContent,rl12,12);






             objScrollView.addView(objRLContent);  // adding contents to scroll view


             objRLScrollView.addView(objScrollView);  // Adding scroll view to a relative layout


             objRLBody.addView(objRLScrollView);  // adding relative layout to body layout



             // adding footer to body

               RelativeLayout objRLFooter=new RelativeLayout(this);
               RelativeLayout.LayoutParams objRLFooterParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,25);
               objRLFooterParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM,objRLBody.getId()); 
               objRLFooter.setLayoutParams(objRLFooterParams);
               objRLFooter.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2e4862"));
               objRLFooter.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
               objRLBody.addView(objRLFooter); 




               this.setContentView(objRLBody); 






      }




     private RelativeLayout addEditText(RelativeLayout objRLContent,RelativeLayout layoutAbove,int i   ) {



            RelativeLayout objRLEditText = new RelativeLayout(this); 
            objRLEditText.setId(1100+i);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams objRLEditTextParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            if(layoutAbove!=null)
            objRLEditTextParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,layoutAbove.getId());
            objRLEditText.setLayoutParams(objRLEditTextParams);
            objRLEditText.setPadding(8, 2, 8, 2);

             EditText objETData = new EditText(this);
             objETData.setId(1300+i);
             RelativeLayout.LayoutParams objETDataParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
             objETData.setLayoutParams(objETDataParams);
             objETData.setPadding(8, 0, 8, 0);
             objETData.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,18);
             objETData.setText(""+i);
             objETData.setSingleLine(true);
             objRLEditText.addView(objETData);           

             objRLContent.addView(objRLEditText);

             return objRLEditText;



     }


}
```

and the above code gives out put as shown below

[image]

The header layouts becomes invisible due to the presence of scrollView. What is wrong with my code? what should i do to get a layout with scrollable contents with  fixed header and footer? plz help.

Comment: No xml file needed I use layout programatically. The above  code  contains no xml file reference

Comment: Why r u setting up layout programatically?  Using XML is easier way.

Comment: @SreejithG iam run your program it'working...

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy are you check the layout allignment?

Comment: @SreejithG edit your answer once try this one..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1- Set your ScrollView's height and width to match_parent.

2- Set your Scrollview's Top and Bottom padding equal to your top and bottom bar height.

3- Set your top bar's alignment to alignparenttop

4- Set your bottom bar's alignment to alignparentbottom

Note: If you want a good compatibility library for action bars consider using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/).

Comment: could have made the answer a little bit more verbose. this is one of those 30-second posts.

Comment: @Mobigital You might have this site confused with [writers.stackexchange.com](http://writers.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Use a LinearLayout instead of a RelativeLayout for your Parent Container. Set the orientation to the LinearLayout to vertical and set a LayoutWeight to 1 for the ScrollView.

Answer (score 2):

Try followin I have edited your code, which working Ok.

```
public class Scrolling2Activity extends Activity {
    int myid = 1000, pos=-1, etpos=-1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        RelativeLayout rlBody = new RelativeLayout(this);
        rlBody.setId(++myid);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams bodyParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        rlBody.setLayoutParams(bodyParams);
        rlBody.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

        //      Header-1
        RelativeLayout head1 = new RelativeLayout(this);
        head1.setId(++myid);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams head1Params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 25);
        head1Params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        head1.setLayoutParams(head1Params);
        head1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        rlBody.addView(head1, ++pos);

        //      Header-2
        RelativeLayout head2 = new RelativeLayout(this);
        head2.setId(++myid);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams head2Params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 25);
        head2Params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, head1.getId());
        head2.setLayoutParams(head2Params);
        head2.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                //      TextView  in Header-2
        TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
        tv1.setId(++myid);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tv1Params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tv1.setLayoutParams(tv1Params);
        tv1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tv1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        tv1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 18);
        tv1.setText("Scroll Test");
        tv1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        tv1.setPadding(4, 0, 4, 0);
        //tv1.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        head2.addView(tv1);
        rlBody.addView(head2, ++pos);

        //      RelativeLayout For ScrollView
        RelativeLayout scrollHolder = new RelativeLayout(this);
        scrollHolder.setId(++myid);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams scrollHolderParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        scrollHolderParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, head2.getId());
        scrollHolder.setLayoutParams(scrollHolderParams);
        scrollHolder.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        scrollHolder.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            //      ScrollView
        ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(this);
        scroll.setId(++myid);
        scroll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        scroll.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            //      RelativeLayout
        RelativeLayout etHolder = new RelativeLayout(this);
        etHolder.setId(++myid);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams etHolderParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        etHolder.setLayoutParams(etHolderParams);
        etHolder.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        etHolder.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 25);
            //      Creating EditTextes  and Adding to etHolder  AS you have done
        RelativeLayout rl2 = addEditText(etHolder, null, 1);
        RelativeLayout rl3 = addEditText(etHolder, rl2, 2);
        RelativeLayout rl4 = addEditText(etHolder, rl3, 3);
        RelativeLayout rl5 = addEditText(etHolder, rl4, 4);
        RelativeLayout rl6 = addEditText(etHolder, rl5, 5);
        RelativeLayout rl7 = addEditText(etHolder, rl6, 6);
        RelativeLayout rl8 = addEditText(etHolder, rl7, 7);
        RelativeLayout rl9 = addEditText(etHolder, rl8, 8);
        RelativeLayout rl10 = addEditText(etHolder, rl9, 9);
        RelativeLayout rl11 = addEditText(etHolder, rl10, 10);
        RelativeLayout rl12 = addEditText(etHolder, rl11, 11);
        RelativeLayout rl13 = addEditText(etHolder, rl12, 12);
        scroll.addView(etHolder);   //  adding RelativeLayout = etHolder  to  ScrollView = scroll
        scrollHolder.addView(scroll);   //  adding ScrollView = scroll  to  RelativeLayout = scrollHolder
        rlBody.addView(scrollHolder, ++pos);

        //      RelativeLayout  for  Footer
        RelativeLayout footer = new RelativeLayout(this);
        footer.setId(++myid);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams footerParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 25);
        footerParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        footer.setLayoutParams(footerParams);
        footer.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        rlBody.addView(footer, ++pos);

        setContentView(rlBody);
    }

        //      Method  as  you  have done
    private RelativeLayout addEditText(RelativeLayout objRLContent,
            RelativeLayout layoutAbove, int i) {

        RelativeLayout objRLEditText = new RelativeLayout(this);
        objRLEditText.setId(1100 + i);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams objRLEditTextParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        if (layoutAbove != null)
            objRLEditTextParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,
                    layoutAbove.getId());
        objRLEditText.setLayoutParams(objRLEditTextParams);
        objRLEditText.setPadding(8, 2, 8, 2);

        EditText objETData = new EditText(this);
        objETData.setId(1300 + i);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams objETDataParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                200, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        objETData.setLayoutParams(objETDataParams);
        objETData.setPadding(8, 0, 8, 0);
        objETData.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 18);
        objETData.setText("" + i);
        objETData.setSingleLine(true);
        objRLEditText.addView(objETData);

        objRLContent.addView(objRLEditText);

        return objRLEditText;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

once try this one

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  //  setContentView(new BallBounce(this));        

       this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
     //  this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        RelativeLayout objRLBody=new RelativeLayout(this);
        objRLBody.setId(1001);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams objLLBodyParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        objRLBody.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d8e4f3"));
        objRLBody.setLayoutParams(objLLBodyParams); 

        /* header portion starts here*/

        RelativeLayout objRLActionBar=new RelativeLayout(this);
        objRLActionBar.setId(1002);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams objRLActionBarParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,50);
        objRLActionBarParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP); 
        objRLActionBar.setLayoutParams(objRLActionBarParams);
        objRLActionBar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2e4862"));

        objRLBody.addView(objRLActionBar);

        RelativeLayout objRLSelectedActionBar=new RelativeLayout(this);
        objRLSelectedActionBar.setId(1003);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams objRLSelectedActionBarParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        objRLSelectedActionBarParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,objRLActionBar.getId()); 
        objRLSelectedActionBar.setLayoutParams(objRLSelectedActionBarParams);
        objRLSelectedActionBar.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        objRLSelectedActionBar.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.LEFT);


        TextView objTVSelectedAction = new TextView(this); 
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams objTVSelectedActionParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        objTVSelectedAction.setLayoutParams(objTVSelectedActionParams);
        objTVSelectedAction.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        objTVSelectedAction.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        objTVSelectedAction.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,18);
        objTVSelectedAction.setText("Scroll Test"); 
        objTVSelectedAction.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        objTVSelectedAction.setPadding(4, 0, 4, 0);
        objTVSelectedAction.setId(1004);
        objRLSelectedActionBar.addView(objTVSelectedAction);  

        objRLBody.addView(objRLSelectedActionBar);

        /* header portion ends here*/

        /* Relative layout which hold scroll view*/
        RelativeLayout objRLScrollView = new RelativeLayout(this); 
        objRLScrollView.setId(1005);
        objRLScrollView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d8e4f3"));
        objRLScrollView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams objRLScrollViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
        objRLScrollViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW ,objTVSelectedAction.getId());


        ScrollView  objScrollView=new ScrollView(this);
        objScrollView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        objScrollView.setFillViewport(true);

        /* contents */

        RelativeLayout objRLContent = new RelativeLayout(this); 
        objRLContent.setId(1006);
        objRLContent.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d8e4f3"));
        objRLContent.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams objRLContentParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
       // objRLContentParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW ,objTVSelectedAction.getId()); 
        objRLContent.setLayoutParams(objRLContentParams);                


              /* adding layouts containing Edittext (for testing scroll view) */

            RelativeLayout rl2= addEditText(objRLContent,null,1);
            RelativeLayout rl3= addEditText(objRLContent,rl2,2);
            RelativeLayout rl4= addEditText(objRLContent,rl3,3);
            RelativeLayout rl5= addEditText(objRLContent,rl4,4);
            RelativeLayout rl6= addEditText(objRLContent,rl5,5);
            RelativeLayout rl7= addEditText(objRLContent,rl6,6);
            RelativeLayout rl8= addEditText(objRLContent,rl7,7);
            RelativeLayout rl9= addEditText(objRLContent,rl8,8);
            RelativeLayout rl10= addEditText(objRLContent,rl9,9);
            RelativeLayout rl11= addEditText(objRLContent,rl10,10);
            RelativeLayout rl12= addEditText(objRLContent,rl11,11);
            RelativeLayout rl13= addEditText(objRLContent,rl12,12);

         objScrollView.addView(objRLContent);  // adding contents to scroll view


         objRLScrollView.addView(objScrollView);  // Adding scroll view to a relative layout

         objRLBody.addView(objRLScrollView);  // adding relative layout to body layout


         // adding footer to body

           RelativeLayout objRLFooter=new RelativeLayout(this);
           RelativeLayout.LayoutParams objRLFooterParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,25);
           objRLFooterParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM,objRLBody.getId()); 
           objRLFooter.setLayoutParams(objRLFooterParams);
           objRLFooter.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2e4862"));
           objRLFooter.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
           objRLBody.addView(objRLFooter); 

           this.setContentView(objRLBody); 
  }

 private RelativeLayout addEditText(RelativeLayout objRLContent,RelativeLayout layoutAbove,int i   ) {

        RelativeLayout objRLEditText = new RelativeLayout(this); 
        objRLEditText.setId(1100+i);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams objRLEditTextParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        if(layoutAbove!=null)
        objRLEditTextParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,layoutAbove.getId());
        objRLEditText.setLayoutParams(objRLEditTextParams);
        objRLEditText.setPadding(8, 2, 8, 2);

         EditText objETData = new EditText(this);
         objETData.setId(1300+i);
         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams objETDataParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         objETData.setLayoutParams(objETDataParams);
         objETData.setPadding(8, 0, 8, 0);
         objETData.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,18);
         objETData.setText(""+i);
         objETData.setSingleLine(true);
         objRLEditText.addView(objETData);           

         objRLContent.addView(objRLEditText);

         return objRLEditText;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

finally I got the desired layout by simply rearrange the order of adding inner layout to the body layout in the above code, and the order is as follows

```
objRLBody.addView(objRLScrollView);
objRLBody.addView(objRLActionBar);
objRLBody.addView(objRLSelectedActionBar);
objRLBody.addView(objRLFooter);
```

also need to set scrollview padding, if we not set padding to scrollview (header layout width as top padding and footer with as bottom) the components view may blocked by header or footer layout.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me well....

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/light_gradient">

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

//put your UI here


    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: ScrollView inside RelativeLayout, not the other way around